# Cual es el meta tag para que el documento html acepte escritura en todos los idiomas?

Tags: html, html5, reactjs

Quiero evitar problemas como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si no me equivoco es: <meta charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 2):

La codificación de caracteres que acepta todos los caracteres, es el UTF-8, así que puedes incluir la meta:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Ahora bien, esa meta no indica "*en que codificación enviará los datos*", si no, "*en que codificación ESTÁN los datos*". De manera que recuerda guardar los archivos de la web en dicha codificación, o no servirá de nada.

Comment: Si esa meta en mi archivo index.html de la carpeta public de mi proyecto en React. Quieres decir que debo agregar en otro archivo ese meta tag?

Comment: No, digo, que todos los ficheros de tu proyecto que contengan texto, los guardes con la codificación UTF-8. Es una opción de tu editor de texto.